# How to get data in json format in informatica?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I have Id and email in flat file, I am using expression transformation, created an output port as string data type, trying to pass the value as below

```
'[
  {
   "Id":"'||Id||'"
   "email":"'||email||'"
  }
 ]'
```

output:

```
"[
  {
   "Id":"2904"
   "email":"k9@gmail.com"
  }
 ]"
```

I don't need the " " at the start and end for square braces and no extra space should be there after line ends .

expected output:

```
 [
  {
    "Id":"2904"
    "email":"k9@gmail.com"
   }
  ]
```

I will pass this string to the API webservice as http request. Kindly help with required format.

Answer (score 1):

In exp transformation create below ports and logic.

```
--assuming input column is datacol
var_str1 = LTRIM(substr(datacol, substr(datacol,'output: '))) -- This will result everything after the word output:.
var_str2 = substr( var_str1 ,2) -- removes first double quote
var_str3 = substr( var_str2 ,-1) -- removes last double quote
out_str= var_str3
```

I did them in step by step process. if you are comfortable, pls combine all into one line.
**EDIT**
var_* - this denotes these are variable ports.
out_  - this output these are variable ports.

Comment: I didn't get this while doing do you mean var_str1 is variable port for first column, out_str is output port. Can you help to use I'd and email ports to do this .. appreciate your help.

Comment: i added explanation. Var3 depends on var2, var2 depends on var1 and so on.